# Java - 2 Arrays of type float - possible loss of precision found : float required : int

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, floating-point

I have 2 Arrays of type float

```
float[] a = new float [100]; 
float[] b = new float [100];
```

I wish to perform the following

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
      a[b[i]]++ // Or a[b[i]] + a[b[i]] + 1;
}
```

Error possible loss of precision found : float required : int

Comment: this is a logic error on your part; I don't think you understand how arrays work. Please read up on them :)

Answer (score 1):

```
a[b[i]]
```

`b[i]` is a float, so you're trying to use a float as an index to an array. The error message is telling you you're using a float but you need an int.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use a float returned by the "b" array for accessing the "a" array. You have to cast to int.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes of arrays are integers, so you can't use a float to try to access a specific element in an array. You'll either need to change the types of your arrays, or convert your float from `b[i]` into an int, then use that as the index to access `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be rude but why?

Regardless you can't reference the index of an array with a floating point value, and that's why you are getting that error. If you really must then you need to cast the value of b[i] to an int.

Comment: That makes sense. I probably don't fully grasp what your ultimate goal here is but from the way I'm reading it this code snippet won't do that.

Comment: My goal is to build a histo.gram, logic here is to loop over each pixel in an image, build a new array of float, which accumulates all the unique brightness float values stored. Im experimenting to see how to accumulate array list of floats by taking all the brightness levels of each pixel and calculating a histo.gram

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has already pointed out that array indexes are integers, but if you cast using `int(b[i]` you may get a rounding error. Try rounding it first and then casting:

```
a[int(Math.round(b[i])]++
```

Comment: Also, no one seems to have noticed that your comment reads 

    `// Or a[b[i]] + a[b[i]] + 1`

I think you meant

    `// Or a[b[i]] = a[b[i]] + 1`